# Sort array by month-year and week- year Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follows :

```
var monthYear = ["1-2016", "7-2015", "7-2016", "3-2016", "8-2016", "2-2016", "6-2016", "8-2015", "5-2016", "4-2016", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015"];
```

In this array shows me the month and year , I want to sort by month and year as follows :

```
var monthYear = ["7-2015", "8-2015", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015", "1-2016", "2-2016", "3-2016", "4-2016", "5-2016", "6-2016", "7-2016", "8-2016"];
```

Similarly with the weeks

```
var weekYear = ["2015-30", "2015-31", "2015-32", "2015-33", "2015-34", "2015-35", "2015-36", "2015-37", "2015-38", "2015-39", "2015-40", "2015-41", "2015-42", "2015-44", "2015-49", "2016-06", "2016-09", "2015-43", "2015-45", "2015-46", "2015-47", "2015-48", "2015-50", "2015-51", "2015-52", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12", "2016-13", "2016-14", "2016-15", "2016-16", "2016-17", "2016-18", "2016-19", "2016-20", "2016-21", "2016-22", "2016-23", "2016-24", "2016-25", "2016-26", "2016-27", "2016-28", "2016-29", "2016-30", "2016-31", "2016-32"];
```

to order it follows

```
var weekYear = ["2015-30", "2015-31", "2015-32", "2015-33", "2015-34", "2015-35", "2015-36", "2015-37", "2015-38", "2015-39", "2015-40", "2015-41", "2015-42", "2015-43", "2015-44", "2015-45", "2015-46", "2015-47", "2015-48", "2015-49", "2015-50", "2015-51", "2015-52", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-06", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-09", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12", "2016-13", "2016-14", "2016-15", "2016-16", "2016-17", "2016-18", "2016-19", "2016-20", "2016-21", "2016-22", "2016-23", "2016-24", "2016-25", "2016-26", "2016-27", "2016-28", "2016-29", "2016-30", "2016-31", "2016-32"];
```

I tried using this function but it does not work :

```
monthYear = monthYear.sort(sortNumber);

function sortNumber(elem1, elem2){
        var as = elem1.split('-');
        var bs = elem2.split('-');
        if(parseInt(as[0])< parseInt(bs[0])){
          if(parseInt(as[1]) < parseInt(bs[1])){
            return -1;
          }else if(parseInt(as[1]) > parseInt(bs[1])){
            return 1;
          }else{
            return 0;
          }
        }else if(parseInt(as[0]) > parseInt(bs[0])){
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }
```

Similarly with the weeks , I wonder if the function is wrong or if there is an easier way to do it .

Comment: for dates its a good practise to put zeros in front of month, date ("09-2015")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a `Date` out of your strings and sort them acccordingly:

```
var monthYear = ["1-2016", "7-2015", "7-2016", "3-2016", "8-2016", "2-2016", "6-2016", "8-2015", "5-2016", "4-2016", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015"];

var sorted = monthYear.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = a.split("-");
    b = b.split("-")
    return new Date(a[1], a[0], 1) - new Date(b[1], b[0], 1)
});
console.log(sorted);
// --> ["7-2015", "8-2015", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015", "1-2016", "2-2016", "3-2016", "4-2016", "5-2016", "6-2016", "7-2016", "8-2016"]
```

And to sort the week:

[Please refer to @mplungjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39082696/3993662)

Comment: Edited it in @mplungjan

Comment: No need to split to sort the week and no need to create a date. It is a huge overhead

Comment: Yes, you're right @mplungjan - your answer is much more efficient than mine

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string and sort by priority without using `Date`.

```js
var monthYear = ["1-2016", "7-2015", "7-2016", "3-2016", "8-2016", "2-2016", "6-2016", "8-2015", "5-2016", "4-2016", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015"],
    weekYear = ["2015-30", "2015-31", "2015-32", "2015-33", "2015-34", "2015-35", "2015-36", "2015-37", "2015-38", "2015-39", "2015-40", "2015-41", "2015-42", "2015-44", "2015-49", "2016-06", "2016-09", "2015-43", "2015-45", "2015-46", "2015-47", "2015-48", "2015-50", "2015-51", "2015-52", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12", "2016-13", "2016-14", "2016-15", "2016-16", "2016-17", "2016-18", "2016-19", "2016-20", "2016-21", "2016-22", "2016-23", "2016-24", "2016-25", "2016-26", "2016-27", "2016-28", "2016-29", "2016-30", "2016-31", "2016-32"];

monthYear.sort(function sort(a, b) {
    var aa = a.split('-'),
        bb = b.split('-');
    return aa[1] - bb[1] || aa[0] - bb[0];
});

weekYear.sort(function sort(a, b) {
    var aa = a.split('-'),
        bb = b.split('-');
    return aa[0] - bb[0] || aa[1] - bb[1];
});

console.log(monthYear);
console.log(weekYear);
```

If you have always the pattern `9999-99` for `weekYear`, you could sort just with the built-in sort.

```js
var weekYear = ["2015-30", "2015-31", "2015-32", "2015-33", "2015-34", "2015-35", "2015-36", "2015-37", "2015-38", "2015-39", "2015-40", "2015-41", "2015-42", "2015-44", "2015-49", "2016-06", "2016-09", "2015-43", "2015-45", "2015-46", "2015-47", "2015-48", "2015-50", "2015-51", "2015-52", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12", "2016-13", "2016-14", "2016-15", "2016-16", "2016-17", "2016-18", "2016-19", "2016-20", "2016-21", "2016-22", "2016-23", "2016-24", "2016-25", "2016-26", "2016-27", "2016-28", "2016-29", "2016-30", "2016-31", "2016-32"];

weekYear.sort();
console.log(weekYear);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate with padding and return the difference

```js
function pad(num) {
  return String("0" + num).slice(-2);
}

function sortXXYear(elem1, elem2) {
  var as = elem1.split('-'),
      bs = elem2.split('-'),
      aa = as[1]+pad(as[0]), // yyyymm
      bb = bs[1]+pad(bs[0]);
  return aa - bb;
}

var monthYear = ["1-2016", "7-2015", "7-2016", "3-2016", "8-2016", "2-2016", "6-2016", "8-2015", "5-2016", "4-2016", "9-2015", "10-2015", "11-2015", "12-2015"];

monthYear.sort(sortXXYear);
console.log(monthYear);
```

No need to use a function to sort the week array

```js
var yearWeek = ["2015-30", "2015-31", "2015-32", "2015-33", "2015-34", "2015-35", "2015-36", "2015-37", "2015-38", "2015-39", "2015-40", "2015-41", "2015-42", "2015-44", "2015-49", "2016-06", "2016-09", "2015-43", "2015-45", "2015-46", "2015-47", "2015-48", "2015-50", "2015-51", "2015-52", "2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", "2016-05", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-10", "2016-11", "2016-12", "2016-13", "2016-14", "2016-15", "2016-16", "2016-17", "2016-18", "2016-19", "2016-20", "2016-21", "2016-22", "2016-23", "2016-24", "2016-25", "2016-26", "2016-27", "2016-28", "2016-29", "2016-30", "2016-31", "2016-32"];

yearWeek.sort(); // No need to use special sort for YYYY-WW
console.log(yearWeek);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const mysort = (a,b) => {
    const [ma,ya] = a.split('-').map(x=>Number(x))
    const [mb,yb] = b.split('-').map(x=>Number(x))
    return ya < yb ? -1 : ya > yb ? 1 : ma < mb ? -1 : ma > mb ? 1 : 0
}

const ywsort = (a,b) => {
    const [ya,wa] = a.split('-').map(x=>Number(x))
    const [yb,wb] = b.split('-').map(x=>Number(x))
    return ya < yb ? -1 : ya > yb ? 1 : wa < wb ? -1 : wa > wb ? 1 : 0
}

monthYear.sort(mysort)
weekYear.sort(ywsort)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just turn each date in the array into an actual date within the custom sort function and sort it by actual date:

```
var monthYear = ["June 2017","October 2018","September 2017"];
monthYear.sort(sortByMonthYear);       

function sortByMonthYear(a, b) {
    var as = a.split(' '),
      bs = b.split(' '),
      ad = new Date(as[0] + ' 1,' + as[1]),
      bd = new Date(bs[0] + ' 1,' + bs[1]);
    return ad.getTime() - bd.getTime();
}
```

Please have a look : [Click here](https://www.webdeveloper.com/d/206670-sort-monthyear-array/4)

Answer (score 0):

here is working code, for monthYear:

```
var monthYear = ["1-2016", "7-2015", "7-2016", "3-2016", "8-2016", "2-2016",
                    "6-2016", "8-2015", "5-2016", "4-2016", "9-2015", "10-2015",
                    "11-2015", "12-2015"];
function sortMonthYear(myarray){
    let temp;
    let tempArr=new Array(myarray.length);
    //make sort friendly
    for (i=0; i<myarray.length; i++){
        temp = myarray[i].split('-');
        if(temp[0]<10){
            temp[0]= "0"+temp[0];
        }
        tempArr[i] =temp[1]+'-'+temp[0];
    }
    //use sort
    tempArr.sort();
    //back to previous format
    for (i=0; i<tempArr.length; i++){
        temp = tempArr[i].split('-');
        if (temp[1].charAt(0)==0){
            temp[1]= temp[1].substring(1);
        }
        tempArr[i] = temp[1]+'-'+temp[0];
    }
    return tempArr;
}
var monthYear = sortMonthYear(monthYear);
console.log(monthYear)
```

for the weekYear a .sort() is enough

Comment: Huge overkill to create all those arrays

Comment: @mplungjan is it better now?

Comment: I made a snippet. It does not seem to work as expected. Seems t0 chop the tens from 10,11,12...

Comment: @mplungjan you are right. I change a little bit my code. problem was I always substring(1) on second function